# Gwt bus event not handled

Tags: java, gwt, mvp

I am working with two presenters that consist of a view each using the gwt mvp design pattern. I have fired an event in one of these presenters(presenter1) and and an event handler in the second presenter. The problem am having is that the handler is never called. I am using a client factory to inject an event bus instance.

```
private static EventBus eventbus;
private static SystemServiceAsync rpc;


@Override
public EventBus getEventBus() {

    if (eventbus == null) eventbus = new SimpleEventBus();
    return eventbus;
}
```

The handler in the second presenter

```
  this.eventBus.addHandler(AskQuestionEvent.getType(), new AskQuestionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onQuestionAskEvent(AskQuestionEvent event) {
            Window.alert("new  ");
        checkForNewQuestion();

        }
    });
```

In the first presenter i call

```
      eventBus.fireEvent(new AskQuestionEvent());
```

Both presenters inject the eventbus in their constructors

```
private final EventBus eventBus;


public PresenterImpl(final View view){
    this.rpcService = clientFactory.getRpcServices();
    this.eventBus = clientFactory.getEventBus();
    bind();
}
```

The handler is called if placed in the same presenter but its never called if in another presenter. What could be the problem here?

Comment: I can't see any reason why this shouldn't work. Can you check in debug mode that both presenters have the same instance of the `EventBus `?

Comment: Yeah, maybe clientFactory is not a singleton, and has different EventBus.